# Windows xp - recover document opened directly from IE

Tags: windows-xp

Attempting to help a family member recover a document. The word 2007 document was downloaded and opened directly from a webmail interface using Internet Explorer running on Windows XP. The user saved the document multiple times while working on it for the good part of a day. After closing Word 2007 the user is not able to locate the document, and I have so far not been able to help. The computer has not been turned off, and the user has not attempted to open the document directly from the mail again.

Recreating the events on vista/windows 7 its easy enough to locate the document under the Temporary Internet Files folder. I have however not been able to do the same on a Windows XP. Any suggestion for how to locate this document, or if its even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Noob error, the files are not stored under their original name in the Temporary folder on Win XP, but rather the as the url they were taken from. Unfortunatly I can't find a way to search on the cached name, and the user can't handle locating the document among the temporary files.

Comment: @Thingfish: Just have the user search for `*.doc`, which will return all Word document files.